# Problem with Postgresql..DatabaseError: Connection terminated

Tags: node.js, postgresql, angular5

we are using pm2 third party middle-ware and the connection is terminating every day with PostgreSQL

[2019-07-17 23:52:47.639] [ERROR] ccd-error-logger - Problem with Postgresql.. DatabaseError: Connection terminated

```
var connectionString = process.env.DATABASE_URL ||  'pg://postgres:root@localhost:5432/13122018';
var pg = require("pg");
var port = process.env.LISTEN_PORT || 5000;
var client = new pg.Client(connectionString);
client.connect(function (error) {
  if (error) {
    ccderrorlogger.error("client Problem with Postgresql" + error);
  } else {
    uiinfologger.debug("client Connected with Database");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're receiving

> "Connection terminated"

errors then you probably have a `.end()` somewhere else in your code that closes the pooled connections.